# Why Windows domain controller reset password for domain computers?

Tags: windows, domain-controller, password, reset

I got message of [4724 event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4724), where domain controller reset password for domain computer.

```
TargetUserName": "COMP123$"
...
SubjectUserName": "DC2$"
```

Why it happened? Is it normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems always to be a bit of non-understanding when it comes to domain-joined (Windows) computers and how/when they update their AD computer object (machine account) passwords.

**Here are a few key points**

- The "default domain policy" setting configures domain-joined Windows 2000 (& up) computers to update their passwords every 30 days (default)
- Computer password update policy is configured in the Default Domain Policy setting
- Computers joined to an AD domain have an associated computer account in AD and that account (object) has an associated password
- This is not "fix": The computer updates the password when it thinks it needs to, but the domain doesn’t block computer accounts with passwords older than the policy setting
- The *local* computer’s Netlogon service handles the machine account password updates, not Active Directory

Or in Short:

> Is it normal?

Yes, it is.